# Using IIS to serve Node/Express API with Reverse Proxy. Problems getting IP client's IP address

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node application that is being served by IIS. I followed this guide and it its all working perfectly:

https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b

Im having an issue I understand why its happening with the IP address (because of reverse routing, NODE its tracking 127.0.0.1 instead of the client's IP).

At Node, Im getting the IP as follows:

```
const ipAddress = req.socket.remoteAddress;
```

Is there a way from Node to identify the IP address that is hitting IIS?

Thanks.

Comment: try this: [How to use X-Forwarded-For header to log actual client IP address?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/how-to-use-x-forwarded-for-header-to-log-actual-client-ip/ba-p/873115)

Comment: I saw that, yes, but it applies to logs when load balancers are in place. I actually went thru the configuration and the IP is being logged but I cant find a way to pass that value to Node when reverse proxying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are reverse proxying, you can do this:

const ipAddress = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.socket.remoteAddress